# xml serialization ad database insert

Tags: xml, xml-serialization

I have a XML file which I read data from, then I insert that data into a sql database. However, when I read my xml I get the following error:

> `<query xmlns=''>` was not expected.
>   There is an error in XML document (2, 2).

This is my code:

```
XmlRootAttribute xRoot = new XmlRootAttribute();
xRoot.ElementName = "items";
//xRoot.ElementName = "query";
// xRoot.Namespace = "http://www.cpandl.com";
xRoot.IsNullable = true;
XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Items), xRoot);
TextReader reader = new StreamReader(@"c:\work\direct.xml");
object obj = deserializer.Deserialize(reader);
Items XmlData = (Items)obj;
reader.Close();
```

This is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<query>
  <query_result>
    <items>
       <item>
        <date>2015-07-14 20:14:47</date>
        <description>Signup Bonus</description>
        <dots>-0.00000</dots>
        <ZAR>-0.00000</ZAR>
        <USD>0.00000</USD>
        <EUR>0.00000</EUR>
      </item>
    </items>
  </query_result>
</query>
```

Comment: What does your class `Items` look like that you're trying to deserialize into?

Comment: HI Marc, thanks for responding please see below.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for responding please see below.

```
public class ItemDetails
    {

        public string  Date { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Dots { get; set; }
        private string ZAR { get; set; }
        private string USD { get; set; }
        private string EUR { get; set; }

    }
    public class Item
    {
        [XmlElement("date")]
        public string Date { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("description")]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("dots")]
        public string Dots { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("ZAR")]
        public string ZAR  { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("USD")]
        public string USD  { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("EUR")]
        public string EUR  { get; set; }

    }

    public class Items
    {
        [XmlElement("item")]
        public List<Item> ItemCollection { get; set; }

    }

    public class Query_Results
    {
        [XmlElement("query_result")]
        public List<Query_Results> QRResults { get; set; }

    }

    public class Query
    {
        [XmlElement("query")]
        public List<Query> QueryCollection { get; set; }
```